# How to use UDF return value as a boolean?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scalar function which returns bit and I'd like to use it in a way as show below:

```
SELECT @SalesPlanExists = 
        IIF(adm.SalesPlanExists(@Year, @Month, @CountryID, 'Country') OR adm.SalesPlanExists(@Year, @Month, @CountryID, 'Region') = 0, 0, 1)

    SELECT
         a.KPI_Application_Count
        ,a.KPI_Application_Count_Plan
        ,a.KPI_Application_Count_Performance
        ,IIF(@SalesPlanExists = 0, 1, b.[Status]) AS KPI_Resolved_Application_Count_Status
    FROM
        #Calcul a

        LEFT JOIN kpi.Indicator b
        ON a.KPI_Application_Count_Performance BETWEEN b.RangeMin AND b.RangeMax AND b.NameID = 10
```

which returns

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'OR'.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this line contain ' = 0'  like this:

```
SELECT @SalesPlanExists = 
        IIF(adm.SalesPlanExists(@Year, @Month, @CountryID, 'Country') = 0 
   OR adm.SalesPlanExists(@Year, @Month, @CountryID, 'Region') = 0, 0, 1)
```